# Difference in month with TIMESTAMPDIFF mysql function in dbplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I am trying to calculate the difference in months between two dates in R using dbplyr package, I want to send the sql query to calculate it using "timestampdiff" native function in mysql but I'm getting an error:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(dbplyr)     

        db_df <- tbl(con, "creditos")

        db_df %>% mutate(diff_month = timestampdiff(month, column_date_1, column_date_2))
```

but the parameter `month` is not been translating correctly because it looks like an object or function in R:

> Error in UseMethod("escape") : 
>         no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of class "function"

And if written this way:

```
db_df %>% mutate(diff_month = timestampdiff("month", column_date_1, column_date_2))
```

I will also get an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `month`, `column_date_1`, `column_date_2`) AS `diff_month`

And I believe this is because dbplyr is writing "month" with double quotes into mysql, and it should be without double quotes, something like this:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, column_date_1, column_date_2) AS `diff_month`
```

Or is there a better way to calculate month difference using dbplyr?

Answer (score 0):

`month` is a function in the `lubridate` package. It looks like mutate is being passed `month` as the R function `month()` instead of as text.

If you are using native SQL to compute the time difference, then you should not need the lubridate package.

Two possible solutions:

1. Remove `library(lubridate)` from your pre-amble and refer to `lubridate` packages using the prefix `lubridate::`. E.g.: `lubridate::ymd_hms`
2. Capitalize the parts of your mutate command that you want run in native SQL. This should help the SQL translation distinguish them from the lower case varients that have other meanings. E.g.:  `db_df %>% mutate(diff_month = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, column_date_1, column_date_2))`

Comment: You unaccepted my answer. Please would you give a reason why?

Comment: We have to use sql function from dplyr to help the code translate the SQL query, I already edit your answer

Comment: This is another approach but it is not essential. The example in my original answer works as expected in my context. Much of the dbplyr advice I have read encourages users to avoid the `sql` function where possible.

Comment: Without `sql` I get an error:  "Error: <SQL> 'SELECT `id_credito`, `fecha_desem`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(`MONTH`, `fecha_desem`, CURDATE()) AS `diff_month`
FROM creditos.desembolsos
LIMIT 11'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.42]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`MONTH`, `fecha_desem`, CURDATE()) AS `diff_month`
FROM creditos.desembolsos
LIM' at line 1"

Comment: Does it work if you replace `CURDATE()` with a hard coded date? E.g. '2019-06-12'. If so, this is different from what you originally posted. For this variation `sql()` may be needed.